# Sagemaker Kernel for tensorflow and pymysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, pymysql, amazon-sagemaker

I am reading from a database using ***pymysql*** while using ***conda_python3*** kernel but, when I want to use tensorflow/keras for deep learning, notebook instance doesn't recognize it.

I tried installing keras and tensorflow libraries but after showing a success message and restarting kernals, I got the same old error that ***"No module named 'keras'"***.

Reading stackoverflow related posts, I was able to temporarily solve the issue with switching to another kernel ***"conda_tensorflow_p36"***.

Do you know any way to avoid switching between these kernels (maybe a better way of installing packages in sagemaker notebook instances?).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer and sharing it here,

Don't install anything in the notebook itself and use the terminal instead,

For the installation you should specify the **name of the package** and **the kernel that you want the package to be installed**. For example,

***conda install -n tensorflow_p36 -c conda-forge pymysql***

[image]